# Understanding Pytorch Weight and Biases in Linear Layer

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, gradient-descent

Below is the code for combining weight and bias into a single layer, I am not able to understand the line below, why we have to multiply weight transpose matrix with bais. I should just bias without weight because we are multiplying weight for getting final output3

combined_layer.bias.data = layer1.bias **@ layer2.weight.t()** + layer2.bias

```
 # Create a single layer to replace the two linear layers
 combined_layer = nn.Linear(input_size, output_size)

 combined_layer.weight.data = layer2.weight @ layer1.weight
 combined_layer.bias.data = layer1.bias @ layer2.weight.t() + layer2.bias //This should be just bias

 outputs3 = inputs @ combined_layer.weight.t() + combined_layer.bias
```

Could anyone please help me in understanding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to expand the original equation of two `Linear` layers i.e.

```
# out = layer2(layer1(x))
# given (x @ A + B) @ C + D
out = (x @ layer1.weight.t() + layer1.bias) @ layer2.weight.t() + layer2.bias
```

You can expand `(x @ A + B) @ C + D = (x @ A @ C) + B @ C + D`

```
out = x @ layer1.weight.t() @ layer2.weight.t() + layer1.bias @ layer2.weight.t() + layer2.bias
out = x @ (layer1.weight.t() @ layer2.weight.t()) + (layer1.bias @ layer2.weight.t() + layer2.bias)
# the above equation is x @ (A @ C) + B @ C + D

# now you can assume
combined_layer.weight = layer2.weight @ layer1.weight
combined_layer.bias = layer1.bias @ layer2.weight.t() + layer2.bias 
# final output
out = x @ combined_layer.weight.t() + combined_layer.bias
```

Also, note that matrix multiplication transpose rule is also used here i.e.

> transpose(A@B) = transpose(B) @ transpose(A)

That's why `combined_layer.weight.t()` is multiplied by x as we didn't take transpose in `layer2.weight @ layer1.weight`.